# 2-d box flipping with css, in addition to cascading flex divs

Tags: html, css, animation, flexbox

*Note:

This question became quite long. I wanted to walk you through my thought process.  Because of the length, I made codepens for those who do not wish to read to the bottom.

Basically I want this formatting with css box flipping effects.
http://codepen.io/KDweber89/pen/MYRaxa

I origionally went down this road:
http://codepen.io/KDweber89/pen/WbWQWV

...and wound up here, getting my css flipping, and loosing my styles. 
http://codepen.io/KDweber89/pen/QwPjeW

I am trying to get the flipping to work out, and the flex styling to remain. Does anybody have any ideas?

## ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

I have this situation in which I have a neat app with some cascading flex divs effects.  I am trying to incorporate 2-d box flipping with each div to provide other types of information.

Here is my original html and css code.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">skittles</div>
  <div class="item">butter fingers</div>
  <div class="item">oreos</div>
  <div class="item">candy</div>
</div>

.row{
  margin: 5% auto;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;  
}
```

This looks beautiful, and it's the framework I want to continue with; 
http://codepen.io/KDweber89/pen/MYRaxa

However I ran into problems when trying to add the flipping element with it.

I initially tried this:

http://codepen.io/KDweber89/pen/WbWQWV

```
.row > .item{   
    position: absolute;
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
    background: white; width: 4em; height: 2em; border-radius: 7px;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}

.row > .itemback{   
    position: absolute;
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 180deg );
    background: white; width: 4em; height: 2em; border-radius: 7px;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}

.row:hover > .item {
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -180deg );
}

.row:hover > .itemback {
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
}


<div class="row">
  <div class="item">skittles</div>
  <div class="itemback">test</div>

  <div class="item">butter fingers</div>
  <div class="itemback">test</div>

  <div class="item">oreos</div>
  <div class="itemback">test</div>

  <div class="item">candy</div>
  <div class="itemback">test</div>
    </div>
```

But realized it is not quite what the solution is.  The consensus that I finally ran into fixed my initial problem in that it allowed me to incorporate awesome box rotating effects....but i wound up loosing the neat cascade flex style because the only way I was able to get it to work was to incorporate a third div within my classes.

http://codepen.io/KDweber89/pen/QwPjeW

```
<div class = "row">
    <div class="threed">
        <div class="item"> skittles </div>
        <div class="itemback"> TEST </div>
    </div>

    <div class="threed">  
        <div class="item ">butter fingers</div>
        <div class="itemback"> TEST </div>
    </div>  
</div
```

So my question simply is simply, can I bring in the flipping effect I desire, while incorporating the cascading flex style I originally was looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your border is missing from your third codepen is because of one tiny issue in this code:

```
.item .itemback {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;  
}
```

Having ".item .itemback" implies that the following rules should apply to .itemback elements *within* .item elements. You should add a comma between them, which means that it would apply to .itemback elements and .item elements, like this: `.item, .itemback`.

I made a few other modifications, which I think is closer to what you're looking to do: http://codepen.io/ebelinski/pen/ByEGMG